# Solving limits of form $\infty \times \infty$

Tags: limits, intuition

I need help with solving $f(x) \lim_{x \to \infty} e^x\times x^3$
I know that $\to \infty$ is the answer but I don't know how to get there. Using since $e^x \to \infty$ and $x^3 \to \infty$ I get $\infty \times \infty$ which isn't allowed. I guess this needs to be rewritten somehow before taking the limit, but how?

Comment: lim = limes? Or do I miss something? I'm unfortunately not a native english speaker or used to solve math in english :(

Comment: @iveqy The English translation of the Latin limes is limit.

Comment: Then limes is correct to use?

Comment: @iveqy "limit" is the correct english term.

Comment: Why should $\infty\cdot\infty$ be disallowed? It's not an indeterminate form. You'd have one for $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}x^3e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

This is one place where going back to the definitions will help. Try to find, for all $M>0$, some $x_0>0$ such that $x>x_0 \implies e^x x^3>M$.

Use the facts you've indicated in your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $x^3\ge 1$ for $x\ge 1,$ so since $e^x>0$ for all $x,$ then $e^xx^3\ge e^x$ for $x\ge 1.$ Now, use this to show that for all $M$ there is some $N>0$ such that $e^xx^3\ge M$ whenever $x\ge N$.

**Added Hint**: Find $N'>0$ such that $e^x\geq M$ whenever $x\geq N'$, then put $N=\max\{1,N'\}.$ Now show that $x^3e^x\geq M$ whenever $x\geq N.$

Comment: I think I need some more hints... I understand it (I think), but fail to understand how to show that I solve it.

Comment: Remember that if $e^xx^3\ge e^x$ and $e^x\ge M,$ then $e^xx^3\ge M.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tilde M := \max(M,1)$ (just technical)
Chose $N = \log(\tilde M) + 1$ then for $x > N$ we have
$$e^x x^3 > e^{\underbrace{\log\tilde M + 1}_{\geq \log M}} (\underbrace{\log\tilde M}_{\geq \log 1 = 0} + 1)^3 \geq e^{\log M} = M$$
So given any $M$, we can find $N$ such that the expression exceeds $M$ for all $x > N$. Thus $\to\infty$.